# Slow Crash with Filter Manager

Tags: windows-7, freeze, crash

I have been having sporadic freezes on my machine lately.  There is no blue screen or crash screen.  All the applications just stop responding and ~5~10 minutes later it will power off.  After checking the event log a couple times, I have found that the same event occurs right before each crash.

> File System Filter 'Avgmfx64' (6.1, ‎2011‎-‎12‎-‎23T08:08:12.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager.

My question is twofold:  I can not seem to find any information on what the Filter Manager actually is supposed to do.  for curiosities sake, what is it?  And more importantly, how do I fix this problem.

From the research I have done, I see that similar problems can be caused by out of date drivers, so I have already taken the time to update all of my drivers, run MemTest, and verify the drive integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Filter Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was added to XP SP2 and up that acts as a sort of software shim and controller, but it is not your problem.

Your problem is with the anti-virus program AVG. Somehow it has gotten messed up. Your best bet is to uninstal it (including running the [removal tool](http://www.avg.com/us-en/utilities)), and then reinstall it from scratch.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about this question.  (In my defense, it is almost a year old.) The filter manager error ended up being a red herring.  The real problem was that the default (one you got from Microsoft Update) version of .NET was not friendly with my machine.  I read a forum post somewhere (which of course I cannot find) claiming that that particular version of .Net was not friendly with triple channel mother boards, (which I know sounds like a load of crap) so out of desperation I tried updating to a version off Microsoft's site, and what do you know, I never saw the problem again.

Comment: Yes, the question popped up because someone had posted a me-too answer yesterday, and the words *Filter Manager* caught my attention because it’s a sort of advanced thing. Well I guess the explanation of your problem makes some sense in a roundabout sort of way. It sounds like some system components were conflicting with your motherboard’s drivers, and by updating .NET (and/or your drivers), the conflict was resolved. That it affected the AVG drivers/services shows how interconnected and convoluted things can get and result in a jumble where error messages can be completely misleading. ¬_¬

Comment: Agreed.  Although, most people with a similar problem are probably going to be more likely to need your answer than mine, so I'll mark yours correct.  Enjoy the Rep.